# Apache2 wsgi threads/processes

Tags: python, apache2, wsgi

I would like to ask you how to configure `apache2` to run my wsgi script. I have developed a Python application which on the one hand does **not** implement threads, locks, etc., but on the other hand, uses logging module. The question is, how should I configure the `app.conf` file for the `apache2`, if I want to run my application in several instances when the server encounters multiple requests at the same time? Moreover, can you please explain me what is the difference between `processes=X` and `threads=Y` while specifying `WSGI DaemonProcess`? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my app.conf file looks like:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIPythonPath /home/brms/brms
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=username group=usergroup threads=4 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /home/brms/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
                Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    Alias /meetingApp /var/www/meetingApp
</VirtualHost>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/brms/wsgi.py
```